# Best way to log a user out of several, owned websites?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have several apps that connect to a central OAuth2 server (this is the only login method). When a user hits *Log out*, I want him to be logged out of *all* the apps **and** the OAuth server.

All the apps are Django at the moment but that might change, so I'm looking for the most cross-framework way to do it. I must also keep in mind that all the apps might handle sessions differently (some server-side, some client-side).

All logouts must be handled by POST requests as the good practice recommends.

The strategy I have in mind:

- On the app, the user clicks on *Log out*
- This *Log out* link points towards the logout page on the OAuth server, on which a POST request to `/logout` is issued immediately (or after a countdown).
- **The session is killed on the OAuth server and the user is logged out of it.**
- A `?next=...` parameter redirects the user back to app A.
- The app pulls the user status from OAuth server (server- or client-side) : **if logged out from the OAuth server, then logout from the app also**.

New apps would just have to implement this pulling mecanism along with the logout link pointing towards the OAuth server logout page, so there's nothing to configure in the OAuth server for new apps.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to follow this draft, https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html